# Create relative path using boost

Tags: c++, boost, filesystems, relative-path

I am trying to create relative paths using boost.

My initial plan was:

```
string base_directory;  // input
boost::filesystem::path base_path;
string other_directory;  // input
boost::filesystem::path other_path;
// assume base_path is absolute - did that already (using complete() 
// if path is relative, to root it in the current directory)  -> 
base_directory = base_path.string();

if (other_path.empty())
  other_directory = base_directory;
else
{
  other_path = boost::filesystem::path(other_directory);        
  if(!other_path.is_complete())
  {
    other_path = base_path / other_path;
    other_directory = other_path.string();          
  }
  if(!boost::filesystem::exists(boost::filesystem::path(other_path)))
  {
    boost::filesystem::create_directory(other_path);
  }
}
```

This works fine, if other_directory is absolute or just a name (or relative inner to base_directory).

But if I try to put ".." or "../other", I end up withe weird constructs, like "c:\test.." or "c:\test..\other"

How can I create relative paths properly, preferably using boost ?  I tried to look in the documentation... without positive success.

I am using Windows (my preference for boost is that this should be multi-platform, and I am already dependent on it)

Edit: I have boost 1.47

Thank you for any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boost filesystem does not know whether `"C:\test"` refers to a file or a directory, so it will not assume a trailing `"\"` is correct.

If you add that `"\"`, you can use the function [`boost::filesystem::canonical()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#canonical) to simplify a path to remove `.` and `..` elements.

```
other_path = boost::filesystem::path( other_directory + "\" );        
if(!other_path.is_complete())
{
  other_path = boost::filesystem::canonical( base_path / other_path );
```

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't seem to be available. I have boost 1.47 (didn't think it made a difference) Prompted by your suggestion, I looked and found a "normalize" in documentation, but it doesn't show in the boost::filesystem (or filesystem3) list

Comment: If there is no option to "canonize" it, I will accept this, I didn't know that it was indeed a valid path - only after this answer I got the courage to test it.

Comment: @Thalia you were so close!  I did a little research and that function was added in [boost 1.48](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#canonical).  :(